# Slack Slash command Text formatting

Tags: python-3.x, slack-commands

Built a slash command using python which has the following output
Comment : XXXXXX
udpatedby: XXXXX

The comment is posted correctly, but i want to format it,
I want Comment to be bold currently and response gets those details
data = {"response_type":"in_channel", "text":response}

wondering if there is a way to format the text output in slack

Comment: Hi, Did you try formatting your message ? https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire response can be formatted by the following example: {"response_type":"in_channel", "text":"`"+new_response+"`"}
will return the values in a coded format